# Is the point of Proverbs 27:23-27 to maintain your farm in case your business fails? Or to choose farming over commerce?

Tags: proverbs

> KJV Pro 27:23  Be thou diligent to know the state of thy flocks, and
>   look well to thy herds.  Pro 27:24  For riches are not for ever: and
>   doth the crown endure to every generation?  Pro 27:25  The hay
>   appeareth, and the tender grass sheweth itself, and herbs of the
>   mountains are gathered.  Pro 27:26  The lambs are for thy clothing,
>   and the goats are the price of the field.  Pro 27:27  And thou shalt
>   have goats' milk enough for thy food, for the food of thy household,
>   and for the maintenance for thy maidens.

Is it perhaps saying that capitalism is intrinsically unsustainable so choose farming? Or just that it is unreliable so "Don't give up your day job".

Comment: Though a farming analogy, it's a general caution to be diligent in the maintenance of your assets. Not just property and possessions, which was the focus of life at the time, but also nowadays, skills and relationships. What fruit is born of one's skills and relationships? If you don't care for them -- "*a little folding of the hands to sleep*" (Proverbs 24:30-34) -- then any value they might have will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

It is not actually written as a complete proverb where the lesson is shown.

KJV Pro 27:23 - It is to be diligent or dutiful to one's own responsibilities, and to look with hope.
Pro 27:24 - Just because you are wealthy, you cannot afford to be lazy.
Pro 27:25-26 - Speaks of a healthy farm in good season.
Pro 27:27 - General wisdom. It is only relatively recently that we have cows milk so abundantly mainly IMHO as the result of a search for greater profiting since goats produce so little by comparison with cows. Goats milk is much more similar to breast milk and is designed to grow an animal of approximately the same size as a human baby to approximately the same size as a human adult whereas cows milk grows something much larger.